# How do I add a synonym for a word in the search index?

Tags: hooks, search

I am looking for a way to add a synonym for a word in the search index.
My function will provide a dictionary for each word that the tool will index, the function will add the synonym if it finds one.

I think use hook_node_update_index but this hook catch each node before being analyzed by the indexing engine.

Is it rather a way to use a hook at a lower level that catch each indexed word 
just before being stored in the index ?

By the way...
I use the core module search not the search Search API module.

Thank you for your help.